# Melexis MLX90395 sensor resolution

Tags: sensor, resolution

I have a Melexis MLX90395 Hall magnetic field sensor, whose datasheet says that the sensitivity is 2.5 uT/LSB.

My question is, does this mean that the resolution, i.e. the minimum value of the magnetic field that I can measure, is 2.5 uT?

Below is a page from the [Melexis MLX90395 data sheet](https://media.melexis.com/-/media/files/documents/datasheets/mlx90395-datasheet-melexis.pdf) showing that value:

[image: Accuracy specification page from MLX90395 datasheet]

Answer (score 2):

No, or at least almost certainly not.

Look at the noise, the hysteresis, and the drift with temperature.  All of these effects cause errors far in excess of \$2.5\mu\mathrm T\$.

You *might* be able to do this if you had a thorough understanding of the physics of the sensor, and added some external circuitry.

If it were just random noise, then you could take multiple samples and average them -- but the temperature drift and hysteresis would kill your accuracy.  If it were not for the hysteresis, then you could temperature-control the chip, or you could calibrate for temperature and compensate.

But you have 60 LSB of hysteresis -- meaning that at any given time a measurement may be off by \$60 \cdot 2.5\mu \mathrm T = 150 \mu \mathrm T\$.  You *might* be able to overcome this*, but if you do there's a good chance you'd find some *other* flaw in the chip that's well in excess of \$2.5\mu \mathrm T\$ that prevents you from reliably seeing changes that small.

---

* With additional circuitry and a deep understanding of how the chip works.

Comment: Regarding the random noise, I am compensating it by means of the average of several measurements as you say, and regarding the temperature drift, in theory the sensor has a temperature compensator in charge of minimizing said error. So I think the only thing that could affect the "ideal" 2.5uT resolution is the hysteresis.
However, for small magnetic field measurements (compared to the range of the sensor, 50mT), around 50 uT, you think hysteresis plays a role. From what I know, I think the hysteresis would be important around the middle of the measurement range, i.e. approx. 25mT. Thanks!

Comment: On the other hand, my original question was also focused on confirming if the "ideal" resolution would be that, interpreting the data sheet in that way. Since, taking into account that the ADC is 16 bits, it had also occurred to me to calculate the resolution as 50mT/2^16 = 0.76 uT

Comment: If someone could answer the two questions above I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: I believe your concept of how hysteresis works is flawed, but you have made it clear that you believe it absolutely.  So I don't see how I have much to add.  Go buy one, get in the lab, and try things out.  I'm not going to adjust my explanation to match what you wish it to be.